# Flask-Socketio Working on localhost but not working when deployed to server

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a simple python application which just sends a message fine on localhost but when I try deploy it to the server I just get bad requests. If I bombard the server with messages every now and again one of them goes through. Any help is much appreciated.

```
from flask_socketio import send, emit, SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('my event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']})

@socketio.on('my broadcast event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Look at the logs in your server for errors. If that doesn't show any clues, see the Troubleshooting section of the Flaks-SocketIO docs for how to enable more verbose logs.